# Search query for 2 text box

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My sql query is :

`$sel = "select * from search where name like '$search%' and price >'$price' ";`

but I didn't get the correct result.

There are some problems in price
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv41x.png)

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: try this `$sel = "select * from search where name like '$search%' and price > $price";` I removed quotes from price

Comment: @Avishek test it bro, it works...or u must read more about php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the `price` without `'...'` just like a `numeric` value not like a `varchar`.

```
select * from search where name like '$search%' and price > $price;
```

Comment: @TheFlash...I posted this before saw your comment... and however your answer is not 100% correct... it still need some modification...

Comment: one more question    what is query of                select * from table where row like '%xyz%'

Comment: @ErSahajArora please explain your question or put your expected result with a demo table or like that. And you can't ask a question in a comment section. You might edit your previous question and add this question there also.